# How to programmatically enable instance storage on Amazon Windows 2008 AMI

Tags: php, windows, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, storage

I'm using a PHP script to **programmatically** create a new Windows instance & run tests on it.

Everything worked fine until I upgraded to use **small instances** (instead of micro). Initially I thought Windows 2008's **C:\ drive size would be 160 GB**, but no, it seems that this space must be *enabled*.

I googled a lot and found that one could programmatically enable this storage using [command line](http://www.serveridol.com/2010/08/30/enabling-instance-storage-on-amazon-windows-2008-ami/) or using [this PHP function **modify_instance_attribute**](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonEC2/modify_instance_attribute)

However, it's still not clear how to do that. **My question is**: is it possible to access this instance storage as **D:\** (for example). **If so, how can I do this in PHP?** ie.

```
$ec2->modify_instance_attribute($instance_id, 
       array('BlockDeviceMapping' => array(
            'DeviceName' => '/dev/sdc=ephemeral0'
       )
));
```

PS. I **don't care** about data integrity, I just need those 160 GBs so that I generate random data on the fly for my automated tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

1. Create your m1.small instance
2. Connect via RDP & go to Start Menu --> Computer --> Manage
3. In the server manager window, GoTo *Storage*, you should find the instance storage in the bottom panel listed as unallocated space (149GB)
4. Right-click on it and choose *Online*
5. Right-click again and mount it as a new hard drive
6. Format this new drive & double check in explorer that it's there
7. **Now** log off, goto Amazon control panel and save this running instance as a new image

That's all. From now on, whenever you launch a new small instance from PHP, your 160GB drive should be **already** mounted and available.

PS. there's no need for the modify_instance_attribute() function, you can do this using run_instances(), ie.

```
<?php
$ec2 = new AmazonEC2();
$ec2->set_region(AmazonEC2::REGION_EU_W1);
$ec2->run_instances($ami_image_id, 1, 1, array(
                    'KeyName'       => 'my-Key',
                    'Placement'     => array('AvailabilityZone' => 'eu-west-1a'),
                    'BlockDeviceMapping' => array(
                              'VirtualName'    => 'ephemeral0',
                              'DeviceName'     => '/dev/xvdb'
                     ),
                     'InstanceType'  => 'm1.small',
                     'SecurityGroup' => 'my-RDP-group'
 ));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to programmatically enable/map [Instance Storage](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html) for an [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) instance after it has been launched, see section *Making Instance Stores Available on Your Instances* in [Amazon EC2 Instance Storage Usage Scenarios](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html#InstanceStore_UsageScenarios):

> Instances that use Amazon EBS for the root device do not, by default,
>   have instance store available at boot time. If you want to use the
>   instance stores with your EBS-backed instance, **you have to explicitly
>   map the instance stores with the devices while launching the instance**. *[emphasis mine]*

The high level steps required to achieve this are outlined on that page as well and cyberx86's answer to [missing ephemeral disks on an m1.xlarge instance](https://serverfault.com/a/335996) provides a nice summary of the two available methods.

Comment: Thank you Steffen! I really don't care about timing (ie. during or after instance launch) as long as I can do it programmatically. So since I `can explicitly map the instance stores with the devices while launching the instance`, the **question is: how can I do this in PHP**?